# decoupling capacitors for DC-DC converters

Tags: dc-dc-converter

I am using a DC to DC converter ([Murata MEJ2S0505SC](https://www.murata.com/en-eu/products/productdetail?partno=MEJ2S0505SC) ([datasheet](https://www.murata.com/products/productdata/8807029800990/kdc-mej2.pdf))) (5 V to 5 V at 500 mA) for isolation purposes. Now I want to calculate the input decoupling capacitor.

Can anyone please suggest any methodology to calculate it? (Note: It is not mentioned in the data sheet.)

Comment: Have you tried simulating it?

Comment: Now i added data sheet,and i did not simulated and i need theritical  explanation.

Comment: The capacitor is usually associated with an inductive element to form a front-end \$LC\$ filter. You dimension these components based on a maximum allowable input ripple current at a certain frequency. Usually a small \$L\$ is adopted as it supports the dc current while a large capacitor can cope with the high-frequency pulses absorbed by the dc-dc module. Have a look at a [seminar](https://cbasso.pagesperso-orange.fr/Downloads/PPTs/Chris%20Basso%20APEC%20seminar%202017.pdf) on filters I taught at an APEC conference in 2017. The example starts slide 80. Don't forget to damp the filter.

Comment: Did you look through their application notes, DCAN-68 "Low power isolated DC-DC application notes"?

Comment: https://www.murata.com/-/media/webrenewal/products/power/appnote/dcan-68.ashx?la=ja-jp

Answer (score 1):

The input filter specifications depend on: (1) your source impedance and (2) dynamic frequency of the DC-DC converter (3) the spectrum of your step load. (4) radiated EMI of source current and conducted noise as a result of (1,2,3)

This is a 2-way filter spec.  If you require load regulation noise on the source, the unbalanced load impedance being the input to the DC-DC can generate noise on the source.

Consider the input cap. as a LPF to the source impedance  including path inductance, both DM and CM.  Ideally, you want 0 Ohms and expect a well-designed DC-DC converter from Murata will have dampened chokes with suitable Q's or L/R ratios.

### Design thought experiment

- Consider the voltage divider relationship of a repetitive pulse with load impedance and the ESR of your input cap
- define your allowed load ripple voltage error / step load current = Step Zout
- Consider the impedance of Cin @ f DC-DC = Zc(f)
- be aware that the C*ESR =Tau product is limited by the type and quality of capacitor material < 10us for low ESR e-cap and > 100us for G.P. e-cap. while Ceramic is lower density much much faster Tau.
- Now define Z cap in  terms of minimum C and maximum ESR @ f for step load I at output ripple Vpp

To meet all the considerations in the beginning; it may end up being a CM choke with two caps in a CLC or Pi filter with a certain differential attenuation Bode Plot that is trivial to design on Falstad's Analog filter site after you define impedance and  attenuation @f.

Comment: Might also suggest using multiple caps in parallel possibly of different types, due to self-resonance and series resistance - to get filtering over a wider range of frequencies.

Comment: Certainly @scorpdaddy,, I imagine the Zcap(C,f,+ESR) of the caps over the load spectrum must be closer to zero than any possible negative incremental resistance For the input Z(V,f) of the DC-DC in the boost startup mode in order to be stable.